# GNU linker flags evaluation on Windows

Tags: eclipse, windows, gcc, ld, ldflags

I'm following [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-auto-incrementing-build-number-your-build-process) tutorial to add an automatic build versioning system on Kinetis KDS(Eclipse CDT, Windows 10).

The example evaluates expressions using Linux shell commands like this

```
-Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_NUMBER=$$(cat $(BUILD_NUMBER_FILE))
```

that obviously doesn't work on Windows.

I tried various combinations using type instead of cat, but none of them worked.

What's the fastest way to define a symbol as the content of a file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the build-number file is a one-liner, then like this:

```
set /p BUILDNO=<build-number.txt
...
gcc ... -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_NUMBER=%BUILDNO%
```